# Is it possible to override a plugin feature with a theme feature

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

So I have a blog based theme that I am working with. I have some basic knowledge of CSS and HTML but am relatively new to this. The plugin that I am working with uses the Wordpress blog page. I have some theme features on my theme which I would like to bring onto the plugin. Mostly stuff from the admin area such as tags/taxonomies, excerpt, rating custom field. etc. What I'd like to know is that is this possible to do?

Edit: Codes that I am trying to replicate on the plugin

**Blog Post Tags**

```
public function garage_post_single_tags($post_id){
    if (!in_array('single_tags', $this->evo_blog_settings())) { ?>
    <div class="evo-post-tags evo-single-top">
        <div class="evo-tags">
            <?php
            if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
                $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '<ul><li>', ' </li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
                if ( $tags_list ) {
                    $span = '<span class="evo-small-title">' . esc_html__('TAGS :', 'garage') . '</span>';
                    printf( '' . $span . '%1$s', $tags_list );
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div><!-- evo-tags -->
```

**Blog Post Excerpt**

```
public function garage_post_excerpt($excerpt ,$length){
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<p>';
    $output .= wp_trim_words( $excerpt, $num_words = $length, $more = '...' );
    $output .= '</p>';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Yes we can override wp features in plugin via theme's functions.php or vice versa. Which exact feature you are trying to override?

Comment: Okay. I am trying to bring the wordpress blog tags feature and the excerpt feature in the plugin.

Comment: @Mohsin I have edited the question to add the code I am trying to override